# My RStudio IDE keeps freezing and becoming unusable-how can I fix this? Already tried quite a lot

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, freeze

For some reason my RStudio IDE on my virtual machine has been freezing up rapidly after inputting just a few commands, it then becomes unusable until I quit the R session and restart from scratch, and then it works for a few more minutes and freezes again. It was fine earlier this week. I've restarted my computer and virtual machine multiple times, uninstalled and reinstalled RStudio, reset RStudio's desktop state as per this advice https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State, and unchecking the Show Diagnostics for R as per this advice https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-running-abnormally-slow-for-every-action-including-cleaning-console-and-saving-file/24878. It's still freezing up! I can't figure out what changed and why. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: When you open R/Rstudio does it load a previous workspace (you will get a message to console after starting) ; some very large objects could be consuming the memory.

Comment: Is your RProj on a local drive or network drive? I've experienced similar slow-downs when working on a network drive, even if not reading/writing files.

Comment: I appreciate your comments! No, I've completely started with a new workspace and I don't believe I'm on a local or network drive.

Comment: I have a similar problem

Comment: Here to say that I was struggling with this issue (freezing using Remote Desktop), and I haven't had any issues since moving my project and files to the virtual computer's local drive.